# Is these a way to add 1 and then after one second than add 2 and than 3 etc

Tags: javascript, html

What I am looking for would essentially be a "++" to a "++" command using native java script. The program simply runs an animation for a given number in which the idea of the animatio is that it adds 1 after one second, two after two seconds and keeps going in the same fashion until the animation is stopped.

```js
var counter = 10;
var animationOn = false;
var counterAnimation;
var plusOne;

function updateCounter() {
  //update the counter value 
  var plusOne = counter++;
  for (var i = 1; i = < 100000000;) {

  }

  //show the counter 
  var counterSpan = document.getElementById("counterHolder");
  counterSpan.innerHTML = plusOne;
}

function startCounterAnimation() {
  if (animationOn == false) {
    animationOn == true;
    counterAnimation = setInterval(updateCounter, 1000);
  }
}

function stopCounterAnimation() {
  if (animationOn == true) {
    animationOn == false;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="startCounterAnimation();">
        Start counter animation 
    </button>
  <button onclick="stopCounterAnimation();">
        Stop counter animation
    </button>
  <span id="counterHolder">6931418</span>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Reading Documentation is not an option https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval

Comment: `var plusOne` makes a local variable, it doesn't assign to the global variable.

Comment: `= <` should be `<=`

Comment: You need `i++`, otherwise it's an infinnite loop.

Comment: `stopCounterAnimation()` needs to use `clearInterval()` to stop the timer.

Comment: What is the `for` loop for, anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't need the `for` loop.
2. You should assign to the global `plusOne` variable, not declare a local variable in the function.
3. You should add `counter++` to it, not assign that directly.
4. Initialize `plusOne` from the number already in the output span.
5. Since your time intervals change between each update, you can't use `setInterval()`. Use `setTimeout()` to make a different timeout each time.
6. Use `=`, not `==`, to assign to the `animationOn` variable.

```js
var counter;
var animationOn = false;
var counterAnimation;
var plusOne = parseInt(document.getElementById("counterHolder").innerHTML);

function updateCounter() {
  //update the counter value 
  plusOne += counter++;

  //show the counter 
  var counterSpan = document.getElementById("counterHolder");
  counterSpan.innerHTML = plusOne;
  counterAnimation = setTimeout(updateCounter, counter * 1000);
}

function startCounterAnimation() {
  if (!animationOn) {
    animationOn = true;
    counter = 1;
    counterAnimation = setTimeout(updateCounter, 1000 * counter);
  }
}

function stopCounterAnimation() {
  if (animationOn) {
    animationOn = false;
    clearTimeout(counterAnimation);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="startCounterAnimation();">
        Start counter animation 
    </button>
  <button onclick="stopCounterAnimation();">
        Stop counter animation
    </button>
  <span id="counterHolder">6931418</span>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: OP wants to add 2 after 2 seconds and 3 after three seconds. You do not need Interval for that. You need to set different Timeout each time.

Comment: I misread, I thought he wanted to add 2, then 3, but didn't see that the intervals change.

Comment: Better, but `100 * counter` is 100ms for first timeout.

Comment: Thank you Barmar this is very helpful. I have made these adjustments but am now met with a NaN value. I have looked into it a bit further and think the issue is with my startCounterAnimation function. I have noticed you put an ! (   for(!animationOn)  ). Is this intentional? Also I am using visual studio. Not sure if this make a difference or not.

Comment: Yes, that's the same as `if (animationOn == false)`

Comment: Did you add `counter = 1` to the function like I did?

Answer (score 0):

You can´t define `var onePlus` in two places, instead define it once and assign a value, var is wide scoped

Also add whatever logic you need in the for loop and put the `onePlus ++` and `counter` as parts of the for loop

As it is now you are expecting to use the `counter` both outside the for loop and as the for loop middle part, which seems reduntant

Try something like(leaving the variable names as are):

```
var counter = 1000
for (var plusOne = 1; plusOne < counter; plusOne++) {
    //Your logic in here

    await sleep(1000);
}

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```